# Processing 2D Array into a List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I want to process this 2D array ('more') in order to get a list of lists ('rm'), so that the final result would look like this:

```
     Month1   Month2   Month3
rm = [[3,       [4],    [5]]    
       2, 
       1, 
       0],
```

where the first column of 'more' corresponds to the Month of data collection at the stations. The final output above has 3 lists for the respective 3 Months of data collection, after removing the -999 values. Note that in the original array data for one month could spread to several rows, but they all end up in one single list in the final output.

I am new to python, so I know I am not doing a good job properly framing this.  I appreciate your help on this.

```
rm = []
       Month  Station1 Station2 Station3
more = [[1,    -999,      3,        2], 
        [1,       1,      0,     -999], 
        [2,       4,   -999,     -999],
        [3,    -999,   -999,        5]]

for i in range(0, len(more)):
    rm.append([])
    r = 0
    for j in range(1, len(more[0])):
        col = more[i][0] - 1
        if (more[i][j] > -999):
            rm[r][col].append(more[i][j])
            r = r + 1

print(rm)
```

with this code  I am getting the error "list index out of range" for the line:

```
rm[r][col].append(more[i][j])
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the index of an empty list which doesn't have any index values. `rm[r][col]` will access the 0 index of rm but then try to access the 0 index of the list you appended which is empty and has no indexes. Instead of appending to a list I think a dictionary would be best to hold the values in a more organized and then easier to convert into an array if you have to have it in one. Myself I would keep it in the dictionary that way you could just refer to the value of the month like so `data[1]` and get the values you need without worrying about indexing.

```
rm = []
       Month  Station1 Station2 Station3
more = [[1,    -999,      3,        2], 
        [1,       1,      0,     -999], 
        [2,       4,   -999,     -999],
        [3,    -999,   -999,        5]]

data = {}
for i in range(0, len(more)):
    if more[i][0] not in data.keys():
        data[more[i][0]] = []
    for j in range(1, len(more[0])):
        if (more[i][j] > -999):
            data[more[i][0]].append(more[i][j])

rm = [v for k, v in data.items()]

print(rm)
```

Which gives this output:

```
[3, 2, 1, 0], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it worked nicely.  I need to get myself more familiar with data structures...  I realize now that I was mixing things up.. cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem, and you could probably use `dict` or other data structures to facilitate the problem. Here's a solution that uses a dictionary to hold the lists. This solution works well because you want to associate the items in the list with a month number, but the same month can span multiple sublists.

In python, you can iterate over lists directly without using indices, if you want indices, you can just do `for index, item in enumerate(list)` rather than using `range` and `len`.

Try:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for row in more:
    for val in row[1:]:
        if val != -999:
            # row[0] stores the month value which we want to key on
            d[row[0]].append(j)

rm = list(d.values())
```

This will still yield the same set of lists in `rm` as before but you lose the association between which values belong to which month. It is probably better to keep them in dictionary format.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comments. Matthew's method was faster as I needed to sieve through a dataset of 30k rows and 70 columns...  thanks again.